# XGBOOST install from windows binary fails

Tags: python, xgboost

guys

I'm trying to install gpu enabled version xgboost, and I followed exact step from [this instructions].(http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/2016/09/22/xgboost-windows-x64-binaries-for-download/)

`git clone https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git xgboost_install_dir`
`copy libxgboost.dll (downloaded from this page) into the xgboost_install_dir\python-package\xgboost\ directory`
`cd xgboost_install_dir\python-package\`
`python setup.py install`

And now after I run all those steps, I successfully installed xgboost into a egg folder called "xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg", under which there is two subfolder "EGG-INFO" and xgboost, but there isn't a folder in my python site-packages called xgboost...like this:

- /site-packages
- /xgboost-0.7-py3.5.egg
- /EGG-INFO
- /xgboost

  I tried to copy paste the xgboost folder into site-package, but the benchmark program still fails. Did I miss something?

Here is the command log [command.log](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/files/1850061/command.log)

### Environment info

Operating System: Windows 10 x64

Package used (python/R/jvm/C++): python 3.5.2 x64

`xgboost` version used: 0.7

Please help me! I just spend most all my money on nvidia 1080ti and I really hope that I can implement this...

Comment: Try building the DLL.  It is easy.  Follow these directions: http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-with-gpu-support

Comment: Also here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/build.md

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have strict version requirements on xgboost,you can try this.

---

First, download binary file of xgboost from this page:https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost

For example, I use python 3.6 and windows 10 64bit version, so I choose this:

xgboost‑0.82‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

you can choose the package accoring your environment.

```sh
$ pip install xgboost-0.82-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
$ python
>>> from xgboost import XGBRegressor
```

Enjoy it!